# laravel paypal ssl eror, package used srmklive / laravel-paypal

Tags: laravel, paypal

**I am integrate laravel paypal by using srmklive laravel-paypal package (in sandbox and localhost) and send data from form to
paypal function and receive the error**

```
public function paypal(Request $request)
    {
       
        $provider = new PayPalClient;
        $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
        $paypalToken = $provider->getAccessToken();
      dd($paypalToken);
    
......
}
```

**recieve the eroor when dump and die at this stage and (in case of  full code it automatically redirect to cancel route) .**

> Error Received : array:1 [▼ //
> app\Http\Controllers\PaypalController.php:23   "error" => " cURL error
> 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token  ◀ " ]

Answer (score 0):

Download and correctly install an updated [CA bundle](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) for your PHP's curl.

Better yet, update or switch to a webserver with a current version of PHP, as whatever you are using is likely to have security vulnerabilities.